# Recursive visibility of symbols in Ada packages

Tags: package, ada, ada2012

Let's say I have a generic vector library. To make it easier to use, I want to instantiate various common forms of the vector library and make them visible in a single package.

I'm trying this:

```
with GenericVector;

package Vectors is
    package Vectors3 is new GenericVector(3);
    use all type Vectors3.Vector;
    subtype Vector3 is Vectors3.Vector;

    package Vectors4 is new GenericVector(4);
    use all type Vectors4.Vector;
    subtype Vector4 is Vectors4.Vector;
end;
```

The end goal is that I want to be able to do `with Vectors; use Vectors;` and end up with `Vector3` and `Vector4` types directly available which Just Work.

Naturally, the code above doesn't work. It looks like the `use all type` statements import the definitions attached to the specified type into the package specification but then those definitions aren't exported to the user of `Vectors`. I have to do `with Vectors; use Vectors; use all type Vectors.Vectors3;` instead. This is kind of sucky.

How can I do this?

Comment: The `use` clause in your package only allows you to use type inside the package, and to export the subtype you declare. You'll be able to declare a `Vector3` variable outside the package without anything else than `use Vectors`, but all operations on your subtypes are not exported so you won't be able to to `V1 + V2` outside the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply make `Vector3` and `Vector4` new types, and not just subtypes.  That would implicitly declare all the inherited, primitive operations from `GenericVector` in `Vectors`.

Comment: But if I did that, they wouldn't be type compatible with `Vectors3.Vector` and `Vector4.Vector`, right? Wouldn't that cause me problems when calling methods on those types which are defined to return a `Vectors3.Vector`?

Comment: Yes.  But why would you declare new operations on `Vectors3.Vector`, when you have `Vector3`?

Comment: I'm not; I was worried that the methods defined on `GenericVector.Vector` which _returned_ a `GenericVector.Vector` would stop working. But it turns out that's not the case, and this approach works fine (although I did have some trouble with some more complex generics). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`use Vectors` gives you direct visibility to those identifiers that are declared in `Vectors`, including those that are declared implicitly.   (Implicit declarations are things like `"+"`, `"-"`, operators when you declare a new integer type, and inherited operations when you declare a derived type.)  But it doesn't give you direct visibility to anything else.  In particular, `use` is **not** transitive, because `use all type Vectors3.Vector` does not declare any new identifiers in `Vectors`.

You could accomplish this by declaring renaming identifiers for everything that you want a `use Vectors` user to see.  (For types, you'd have to use `subtype` since there's no type renaming in Ada.)  E.g. in `Vectors`:

```
function Dot_Product (V1, V2 : Vectors3.Vector) return Float
   renames Vectors3.Dot_Product;
```

(I'm just guessing at what the operations in `GenericVectors` might look like.)  Now, anywhere that says `use Vectors` will be able to use `Dot_Product` directly.  You'd have to do something like this for every identifier, though.  If there are a lot of them, this probably isn't a viable solution.  (The renaming declaration doesn't have to use the same name `Dot_Product`.)

Although it may seem annoying that you can't get this kind of transitive visibility, the alternative probably would turn out to be more annoying, because you can't look at `Vectors` and see what identifiers would be made visible by `use Vectors`; the result would probably be either unexpected name conflicts or other surprises.